# What does "Spuren der kurzen Nacht" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, german-to-english

What does "Spuren der kurzen Nacht" mean?

Found [here](https://www.steuerberatertag.de/aktuell/wir-machen-sie-nachhaltig-erfolgreich):

> Rund um den Deutschen Steuerberatertag bringen wir Sie und Ihr Team
> aber nicht nur fachlich und organisatorisch in Bestform – auch
> körperlich werden Sie gefordert: Joggen am Morgen, Tanzen am Abend,
> Yoga gegen die **Spuren der kurzen Nacht**.

I have checked Duden, Oxford and Collins - both under *Spur* and *Nacht*, but couldn't find this usage.

Comment: I see no special context here. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/spur) provides *Spuren hinterlassen (fig) to leave one’s/its mark*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means the negative effects ('traces') of not having enough sleep. The relevant definition of 'Spur' is #2 in [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Spur):

> 2. von einer äußeren Einwirkung zeugende [sichtbare] Veränderung an etwas, Anzeichen für einen in der Vergangenheit liegenden Vorgang, Zustand

Comment: Maybe "marks" is a better translation than "traces" in this context.

Answer (score 7):

It means it's clearly visible (mostly in your eyes, face) and maybe because you're a little dizzy because your night was short (often implies partying, alcohol and more).